# Can we use ternary operator within string template or jsonencode in terraform

Tags: terraform

Can we use ternary operator within string template or jsonecode function.

Example:

```
event_pattern = jsonencode({{
    "detail-type" : ["Step Functions Execution Status Change"],
    "detail"      : {
    "stateMachineArn" : ${var.sfn_arn} != "" ?  [${aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.arn}, ${var.yourapp_sfn_arn}] : [${aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.arn}],
    "status"          : ["FAILED"]
  },
    "source" : ["aws.states"]
  })
```

OR in string template:

```
event_pattern = <<-EOF
{
    "detail-type" : ["Step Functions Execution Status Change"],
    "detail"      : {
    "stateMachineArn" : ${var.sfn_arn} != "" ?  [${aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.arn}, ${var.yourapp_sfn_arn}] : [${aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.arn}],
    "status"          : ["FAILED"]
  },
    "source" : ["aws.states"]
}
EOF
```

Comment: Did you test this? If so are there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the entire expression inside the `${}` brackets, like this:

```
"stateMachineArn" : ${var.sfn_arn != "" ? [aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.arn, var.yourapp_sfn_arn] : [aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.ar]},
```

The `${}` interpolation brackets evaluate the expression inside of them. You use it to wrap an entire expression, not individual variables in an expression.

---

I find these expressions inside strings to be very difficult to read, and I wouldn't recommend doing this at all. I think a much better approach is to use local variables:

```
locals {
  stateMachineArn = var.sfn_arn != "" ? [aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.arn, var.yourapp_sfn_arn] : [aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.ar]
}
```

This way your possibly complex expressions can be in pure Terraform code, outside of the string template. Then in the string template you just reference the local varaible:

```
"stateMachineArn" : ${local.stateMachineArn},
```

---

In either case, this really only works with the `jsonencode()` approach, since it will handle converting your list values into the correct JSON format with comma separated, quoted string values. The Heredoc `<<-EOF` approach won't convert that list value to the correct string format.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, one query though how can we convert the list value to acceptable string format ? `jsonencode`

Comment: Yes, as I said at the end of my answer, `jsonencode` will handle converting the list into the correct JSON format for you.

Comment: the `plan` was failing with below error
   ├────────────────
    │ aws_sfn_state_machine.myapp.arn is a string
    │ var.sfn_arn is ""

Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

Comment: Edit your question to include your updated code that generates that error message if you want help with it. I can't understand from that error message what you are doing.

Comment: Sure for now i will use the second option seems the right way to do it. Thank you